# Can we use Scala to Perform UPDATE and DELETE operations on Databricks Delta tables?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

I am able to create databricks delta tables using scala and able to  perform append and overwrite operations over it.

Is there any way I can perform DELETE and UPDATE operations using scala and not through Databricks runtime.

```
val target = Seq(
  Data("a", "0"),
  Data("b", "1"),
  Data("c", "2"),
  Data("d", "3")
).toDF().write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("target")
val DF1 = spark.table("target")
DF1.show()

val NewInserts = Seq(
  Data("a", "0"),
  Data("b", "1"),
  Data("c", "2"),
  Data("d", "3")
).toDF().write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("target")

val DF2 = spark.table("target")
DF2.show()
```

Comment: scala is language and Databricks runtime is a library. You can use Databricks runtime using scala as an language. Can you please elaborate more on the question?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet!  Only sql commands support the update/delete/merge.  Databricks is working on releasing the scala/python equivalents.